# Problem with CRLF Injection (using cookies)

Tags: c#, asp.net, setcookie, veracode, crlf-vulnerability

I used VeraCode to validate my code, in the validation, I found a vulnerability type CRLF Injection, because, I used some cookies. I tried to solve, with the tag `httpOnlyCookies=true` in `web.config` file, or with `CookieName.HttpOnly = true` in C# code behind, but It is not passing the validation in VeraCode. Do you have any idea?

This is my code, I declared the cookie in a superclass UserInfo.cs:

```
private HttpCookie httpCookie = null;

public UserInfo()
{
    if (this.httpCookie == null)
    {
        this.httpCookie = this.Context.Request.Cookies["ExampleCookie"];
    }

    if (this.httpCookie == null)
    {
        this.httpCookie = new HttpCookie("ExampleCookie");
        this.httpCookie.HttpOnly = true; //I tried with this too
        this.Context.Response.Cookies.Set(this.httpCookie);
    }
}

static public UserInfo GetCurrent
{
    get
    {
        return new UserInfo();
    }
}

public string UserName
{
    set
    {
        this.httpCookie.Values["UserName"] = value.ToString();
        this.Context.Response.SetCookie(this.httpCookie);
    }
    get
    {
        return this.httpCookie["UserName"] == null ? string.Empty : this.httpCookie["UserName"].ToString();
    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<system.web>
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" />
```

Comment: HttpCookie.HttpOnly gets or sets a value that specifies whether a cookie is accessible by client-side script. A CRLF injection issue refers to inserting a malicious [CRLF sequence](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CRLF_Injection). These are two different things and why setting the HttpOnly property is not helping you.

Comment: You need to scrub your cookie data to ensure it doesn't have any CRLF sequences (e.g., in the `UserName` setter, `this.httpCookie.Values["UserName"] = value.Replace("\r\n", "");`. [BTW, `value` is a `string`, so there is no need for `.ToString()`.]

Comment: @HereticMonkey If I add the tag enableHeaderChecking="false" in web.config, will it also work?

Comment: Unlikely. Veracode will probably then complain about that. You should concentrate on fixing the underlying vulnerability rather than how to get around it.